# React Native | What does this mean: <> </>

Tags: javascript, react-native

What does this thing I see with react native 0.62 data? If I wiped I couldn't see an effect.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>       <-here
    </>      <-here
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [short syntax for a React fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax).

JSX can only return a single "thing" so:

```
return (
   <div>Hello</div>
   <div>World</div>
);
```

… would be invalid.

A fragment allows those elements to be grouped.

```
return (
   <>
       <div>Hello</div>
       <div>World</div>
   </>
);
```

Comment: I understand. So now we use this "<>" instead of React.Fragment. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

That's the short syntax of writing

```
    <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>
```

However, the tags don't have any children (other nested tags or components) so it won't make a difference.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much.